# Error displayed in multi store

Tags: magento2

I Created Multi-Store option in the localhost, Store has been created. But load from one store to another

> Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.

message displayed.

[image]

Comment: try to flush cache and then refresh the page

Comment: I am flushed the cache, but the same error is repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your **`web/secure/base_url`** and **`web/unsecure/base_url`** from **localhost** to **127.0.0.1** or your local **IP address**